# What would be the correct tag for "underwater vertebrates" like whales, dolphins, etc.?

Tags: support, tags

I had posted a question about whales, and I wondered which tags to use.
In biology I had leaned that whales are *not fish*, so I didn't want to use the [fish](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish) tag.
However using the [vertebrate](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertebrate) tag seems to be rather unspecific.
So what tag should I have used, or should there be a new tag being created for that?

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly we have quite a few questions about whales but no one chose to use a tag "whale" so far. A lot of them used the "marine-biology" tag together with some more specific ones depending on the question. You could also add the "mammal" tag.

Comment: I agree. @U.Windl, add the "marine-biology" and "mammals" tags. Though, if your question is about vertebrates more broadly, then the broadly-applicable "vertebrates" tag is appropriate as vertebrates are a broad group. Whales are not fish, so if your focus is on [cetaceans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cetacea) specifically, please do not use the ichthyology (study of fish) tag. Thanks!